# Sending captured data from an API in node.js to a html table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, web-applications

I'm learning node.js and working on a project for creating an web application to manage stock market portfolio for investors. I don't know how to send the captured data from an API to a table cell in html.
Here is my node.js code

```js
  node.js file

const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extented:true});

app.get ("/", function(req,res){

//The stock market API
  const url= "https://api.{stock-market-api}"

//https get request to API
  https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data){
     //converting the API jason data to javascript object
      const stockDataObject = JSON.parse(data);
    //capturing the data I want to a const name companyPrice      
     const companyPrice = stockDataObject.data.comapny1.IN3wmk;
    })
  })


});


app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("sever is running");
})
```

```html
html file

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>document</title>
    <style media="screen">
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Market portfolio</h1>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>table head1</th>
        <th>table head2</th>
        <th>table head3</th>
        <th>table head4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I send the the data I captured from "const comapnyPrice" to the data4 cell in td element in html table. Please help me as I'm a very beginner to coding. Thank you very much

Comment: How are you serving your html file?

Comment: instead of that, why don't you use template literal to render the entire table. Its an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a lot to unpack here as you say you're a beginner. It would be more like a lesson telling you how to make a major part of your application, rather than an answer fixing a bug. All I can do is point you to some resources that might help you.

[EJS Documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs)
This is for what's called server-side rendering. With this you'll be able to put the data into the file before serving it to the client.

[Fetch Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
Use this if you would want the client to query data. (Meaning the data is loaded through a script file on the page itself)

[About Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)
`fetch` has quite a lot of references to promises and async functions, so this will be of huge help to you. From looking at your code it also seems you'll be running into callback issues (you will probably try to access `res` in a callback at some point, which wouldn't be a good idea). Using async/await will help you to get around those issues.

PS: Sorry if this isn't what you expected as an answer, I'm just trying to help you out.

Comment: I managed to pass the data to the html through ejs templating. thank you